# How to get complete JSON Response in android logcat Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

How to get full JSON Response in android `Logcat` Retrofit2.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [HTTP Logging interceptor](https://howtodoinjava.com/retrofit2/logging-with-retrofit2/) or the second way is to print the response but 1st way is preferred.